# Windows guest on KVM/Qemu suffers horrible key lag

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

Host OS is Arch Linux with the following versions:-

qemu 2.1.0-2
libvirt 1.2.7-1
linux 3.15.8-1

Guest OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

This problem did not exist when I first created this VM and started using it, but rather appeared at some point. I can't unfortunately pin it down to a particular host or guest configuration change or software update.

When running the VM with the virt-manager viewer, key presses take slightly less than a second to register. Mouse actions are not delayed. The machine is not noticeably running slowly overall - the delay appears to be only in keyboard input.

Here's the definition of the machine:-

```xml
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>Windows7</name>
  <uuid>ad22629b-64eb-7444-359f-f97d458336cb</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>2097152</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>4</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-1.5'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Nehalem</model>
    <vendor>Intel</vendor>
    <topology sockets='1' cores='2' threads='4'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='avx'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='vme'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='dtes64'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='xsave'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='vmx'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='xtpr'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pcid'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='est'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='monitor'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='tm'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pclmuldq'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='acpi'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='tsc-deadline'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='osxsave'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='tm2'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ht'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pdcm'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ds'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='rdtscp'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ss'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pbe'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ds_cpl'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/sbin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='writethrough'/>
      <source dev='/dev/volgrp1/qemu_windows7'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
      <source dev='/dev/mapper/volgrp2-qemu_windows7_data'/>
      <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='direct'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:f0:f8:5b'/>
      <source dev='eth0' mode='bridge'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:c4:a5:2a'/>
      <source network='isolated'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='spice' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the issue could be? I can't find any useful Google links. I was hoping that it would be a bug that would vanish again, but it has persisted over several version of Qemu + kernel now.

Comment: Issues like this led me to get rid of Arch Linux. This is a situation where you want _something that works_, not the latest poorly-tested code.

Comment: agreed. Spice, QEMU, KVM, libvirt - all of these are essentially Red Hat projects. Try it on Fedora if you wannt the latest and greatest or on RHEL/CentOS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a distro problem, but a bug in Windows:

http://keyliner.blogspot.se/2009/11/windows-7-slow-keyboard-response.html (second clause)

That is what helped me:

1. Start, Run, `regedit`
2. Find this key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters`
3. On the detail side, right-click the blank area and add a new "DWORD (32-bit)" value. Name the key `PollStatusIterations`.

   Set value to Hex = 1

   Caution, there are other registry keys with similar names.
4. Close Regedit and reboot.
5. If this value is already in the Registry, disable the key by renaming it to `xxPollStatusIterations` (right-click, Rename). Reboot and test.

Comment: I was sceptical, but that actually worked! Amazing. You are a genius. I can now use my Windows VM again.